# swagger ui is not showing unused model

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui

Does swagger ui only display models that are used by controllers?

In my spring boot application, I am using swagger 2 to define my api. Few of the models are being used in apis whereas others are not being used directly but I need them in my api doc.
Now when I see the json in swagger editor it displays everything perfectly but swagger ui is only displaying models that are used by controller. Following are my swagger-ui configurations

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.search.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

It will helpful if anyone could share some feedback on this. Also is there any other tool that could serve this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: If you are creating a new project, consider using 'springdoc-openapi' (basically swagger3, 
 with better integration in Spring). It only requires one dependency and requires no configuration of any kind for basic use. Aka, works out of the box...

Comment: And yes, I think Swagger only documents your API endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the generated json or yaml file:

- localhost:8080/v2/api-docs
- localhost:8080/v2/api-docs.yaml

Edit it to your liking, and use your own documentation source instead.

(This might help with that:
http://editor.swagger.io)